# SELinux Sandbox Usage

Tags: linux, fedora, selinux, sandbox

What am I doing wrong in the following, from the man file and internet it looks like this is right.

```
$ echo "hello world" 1> test 
$ sandbox -i test cat test
/usr/bin/cat: test: Permission denied
```

Answer (score -1):

`sandbox -M -i test cat test` worked for me